# Illegal Characters in path when grabbing text from a file?

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting illegal characters in path, but the directory (the path) will be different for everyone, so I'm not setting a value for the "path", it's what the user chooses in the file explorer.

I haven't seen a solution for VB.net yet so here's the code I have now:

```
myFileDlog.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
myFileDlog.Filter = "Txt Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
myFileDlog.FilterIndex = 2
myFileDlog.RestoreDirectory = True

If myFileDlog.ShowDialog() =
    DialogResult.OK Then
    If Dir(myFileDlog.FileName) <> "" Then

    Else
        MsgBox("File Not Found",
               MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If
End If

'Adds the file directory to the text box
TextBox1.Text = myFileDlog.FileName
Dim fileReader As String
fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(myFileDlog.FileName)
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileReader)
```

At `Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileReader)`

It breaks with the Illegal Characters in Path exception, and I'm not sure how to test where the illegal character is, because it's grabbing from your own file directory. Any help with this?

Comment: `it's grabbing from your own file directory` No, that code is using all the text in the `myFileDlog.FileName` file as a filename

Comment: The [**Autos window**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd.aspx) is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem originated from this line:

```
Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(myFileDlog.FileName)
```

`fileReader` takes all string contents from the corresponding file name and pass it into [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) method at next line, throwing `ArgumentException` with illegal file path message if illegal characters found inline.

Correct way to read file contents using `ReadAllLines` is using predefined file path or directly using [`FileDialog.FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) property as argument given below:

```
Using myFileDlog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

   ' set dialog filters here

   If (myFileDlog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
      If Dir(myFileDlog.FileName) <> "" Then
         Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(myFileDlog.FileName)

         For Each line As String In lines
            ' do something with file contents
         Next
      Else
         ' show "file not found" message box
      End If
   End If
End Using
```

Since `ReadAllLines` already being used to fetch all file contents, usage of `ReadAllText` may be unnecessary there.

Comment: This worked. I ended up using it to put each line of the text file into a listbox to store. Have had this problem for a while, glad I have a fix.